# Last-Modified header is wrong date on Nginx

Tags: nginx, last-modified

Today, Feb 24 2017, I updated some static files on my server. 
But the response header I get is:

```
Last-Modified:Thu, 19 Jan 2017 19:17:33 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.3
```

Which was more than a month ago. 
Why is the last-modified header not updated?

When I list the files on the shell through `ls -l` it clearly shows the file has been modified today:

```
ec2-user ec2-user  15298 Feb 24 20:33
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not. I stopped relying on it.